# How to set a specific resource in MS Project to have a max work capacity of 7 hours a day?

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, resources, ms-project-2016

I'm working on this slightly complicated project schedule in MS Project 2016. I'm not new to MS Project and have used it for several years, but not necessarily an expert either. For my project, I need to configure it such that although the custom project calendar that I'm using has an 8-hour work day for everyone, for one particular resource, I need the max work day to be 7 hours. How would I achieve this?

My thought was that I open the Resource sheet, select that reviewer, and edit their Resource Information to have a max availability of 87.5% (if 8 hours is 100% max capacity). Is this the right way to approach it? Or is their a better, more direct way to achieve this?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Project, you can set a unique schedule for a specific resource (Applicable to MS Project 2007+).

**Step 1:** Click Project > Properties > Change Working Time.

[image]

**Step 2:** Choose a resource from the For calendar list.

[image]

**Step 3:** Choose the right Base calendar for the resource.

[image]

**Step 4:** If the working times in the calendar aren't quite right for this resource, click the Work Weeks tab, and then click Details.

[image]

**Step 5:** Select the day(s) that you want to change the working times for, and then choose whether you want them to be working or nonworking time.

[image]

**Step 6:** If you chose Set day(s) to these specific working times, use the From and To columns to set the working times for the selected days. ( You can set 7 Hours here)

[image]

**Step 7:** Click OK to return to the Change Working Time dialog box, and then click OK again.

Refer this Microsoft resource - [Set a unique schedule for a specific resource](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-a-unique-schedule-for-a-specific-resource-ab816ff2-f39d-43b7-b143-ab36d03baaad)